# Express Gaussian process similar to Ito diffusion form

Tags: linear-algebra, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I have been wondering for a while now, and it my be a bad question, if a realization of a Gaussian process can be written and generated similar to an Ito diffusion.

From what I know, a Gaussian processes is generated from the covariance kernel K(x,x') and so can Brownian motion.

This is the Ito form: $ dX(t)=\mu dt+\sigma dW(t) $

So because diffusion has time, then my guess the gaussian kernel would be K(x,t)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are asking - your last line doesn't really make sense to me, and I don't know what you have in mind when you say "similar".  But one possibly relevant example is fractional Brownian motion, which is a Gaussian process that is not a semimartingale and thus has nothing like an Ito decomposition.

Comment: @NateEldredge  I saw the following form somewhere $y(x) =f(x) + \sigma \epsilon$ but how do I express that as a derivative